# Continuously avoiding closed balls in a proper metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a proper metric space (closed balls are compact), and $r :[0, \infty) \rightarrow X$ be a continuous and proper (inverse image of compact is compact) map, with $r(0) = x_0$. Therefore, given a radius $R$, there exists $N_R > 0$ such that $r([N_R, \infty))$ avoids the closed ball $\overline{B}(x_0 ; R)$. Can the choice $R \mapsto N_R$ be made continuous in $R$? My last [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2728883/26141) came out of a very naive (and unsuccessful) attempt of doing so.

Comment: How is that choice made for large r when X is bounded?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $X$ is non-compact because the map $r$ is assumed to be proper. On the other hand, the closed balls are assumed to be compact.

Comment: What if r = sin?

Comment: Consider X = {0}.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Again, because $r$ is assumed proper, the image of $r$ (in fact anything containing the image of $r$) has to be non-compact.

Comment: For $R>0$ let $f(R)=2\cdot \sup \{x: r([x,\infty))\cap \overline B(x_0,R)=\emptyset\}.$  Does this work?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You mean $\inf$ instead of $\sup$. Still showing that this function is continuous does not seem to be trivial. [Michael selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_selection_theorem) might be helpful here. The multivalued function $f(R)=\{x\ |\ r([x,\infty))\cap D(r(0), R)=\emptyset\}$ may work. $X$ is paracompact, values are nonempty and convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. The only problematic property is lower hemicontinuity.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm afraid not. Take $r:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ to be the zig-zag function defined in the answer of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Start with the function $f:(0, \infty) \to (0,\infty)$ defined by 
$$
f(R) = 1 + \inf\{t : r([t, \infty))\cap \overline{B}(x_0, R) = \varnothing \}
$$
This function may be discontinuous, but it is *nondecreasing*. For any such function there exists a continuous function $g:(0, \infty) \to (0,\infty)$ such that $g(R)\ge f(R)$ for all $R$.  (One may say that $f$ has a *continuous majorant*.)

*Proof*: First put a staircase on top of $f$, for example 
$h(x) = f(\lceil n\rceil)$ does the job (it's a piecewise constant function). Then roll a carpet over the staircase, producing a piecewise linear function majorizing $h$. Putting this together in a formula, 
$$
g(n+\alpha) = (1-\alpha)f(n+1) +\alpha  f(n+2),\quad n\in\mathbb Z, \quad \alpha\in [0, 1)
$$
The fact that $g\ge f$ follows from 
$$
 (1-\alpha) f(n+1) + \alpha f(n+2) 
\ge (1-\alpha) f(n+\alpha) + \alpha f(n+\alpha) = f(n+\alpha)$$
The continuity follows from $g$ being linear on each segment $[n, n+1)$ and being continuous at the endpoints: $g(n) = f(n+1)$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: The definition of $g$ says $g(n) = f(n+2)$. Did you mean to interchange $\alpha$ with $1-\alpha$? Neat solution btw with a generally useful technique: dominating any increasing function with a continuous one.

Comment: Yes, I had the coefficients misplaced. Fixed now.